# How to use po, or equivalent, to inspect iVars in the console or Xcode in general?

Tags: xcode

The po command is a bit useless, at least unless there are some runes one has to cast to make it useful, in which case what are they?

For example, take this code:

```
MyClass *myClass = ...
NSLog(@"stuff: %@", myClass.stuff);
```

If running this code in Xcode and trying to debug then po behaves as:

```
(gdb) po myClass
<MyClass: 0xee34567>

(gdb) po myClass.stuff
There is no member named stuff
```

Why does it do this. There is a property called stuff, and NSLog has no problem seeing it. So how to inspect member variables in Xcode, I know this question has been asked on here many times before, but after reading them I still can't find a decent way of doing so.

Comment: Obj-C properties use C struct syntax, but apply it to pointers to structs, rather than to structs themselves. Hence "no member named". However, gdb understands "normal" Obj-C message syntax, so [myClass stuff] works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is for Objective C, specifically. `po` only works with ObjC objects so I'm assuming that's what you're asking about here.

Have you tried:

```
po [myClass stuff]
```

This works fine for me - assuming `stuff` is a property.

`po myObj` is equivalent to calling `[myObj description]`. If you want to list all the ivars of a particular object using `po` you'd have to implement a suitable `description` method for its class. I am not aware of any automatic mechanism for listing the ivars of a class. There may well be, at least if you are dealing with properties.

This is worth a read too: [gdb for Objective C](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/10/debugging-tips-for-objective-c.html).

Comment: Cool ta. Is there a command to display all instance variables belonging to myClass?